# Name of this function in built-in Emacs Lisp library?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

The following Emacs Lisp function takes a list of lists and returns a list in which the items of the inner lists have been concatenated to one big list. It is pretty straight-forward and I am convinced something like this must already be part of the standard function library.

```
(defun flatten (LIST)
  (if LIST
      (append (car LIST) (flatten (cdr LIST)))
    nil))
```

I am looking for a function that will take a single list of lists as its argument and then append all the inner lists.

```
(flatten '((a b) (c d)))
```

will give

```
(a b c d)
```

Does anyone know whether this function is already built in, and if so, under which name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

You're either looking for append:

```
(defun flatten (list-of-lists)
  (apply #'append list-of-lists))
```

If (and only if) you know that you'll always have a list of lists.

Otherwise:

```
(defun flatten (list)
  (mapcan (lambda (x) (if (listp x) x nil)) list))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, very elegant definitions. But anyway, my question was not so much for a way to achieve this behavior, but whether ELisp already provides such a function. This is really more out of curiosity, not because I'm facing a specific problem that seems very complicated...

Comment: The answer is, "yes, it does", namely mapcan over the identity function.

Comment: I don't think so: mapcan takes two arguments (the identity function and a list) while the suspected "flatten" takes only a list. (Where is Curry when you need him?) Anyway, as I said before, it's not really important, and vatine's solutions above are both great.

Comment: It's not recursive. :-(

Answer (score 13):

Emacs 27.1 has `flatten-tree`:

```
(flatten-tree '((a b) (c d)))

(a b c d)
```

See: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Building-Lists.html

Comment: This is the actual answer to the question.

Answer (score 7):

I stepped into this only recently whilst looking for something different; there is something that might not have been put into evidence by the test data utilized to check the function, depending on whether the original question was meant to refer to generic lists (i.e.: list of list of list of list of...) or just to two-level lists (as in the example).

The [solution based on `append`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969067/name-of-this-function-in-built-in-emacs-lisp-library/969320#969320) works fine only with two-level lists, and there is a further issue with the [solution based on `mapcan`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969067/name-of-this-function-in-built-in-emacs-lisp-library/969320#969320).

Basically, the general solution has to be recursive both on car and cdr, as in the `flatten` defun below.

```
(setq l '((((1 2) 3) 4) (5 6 7)))

(defun flatten(x)
  (cond ((null x) nil)
    ((listp x) (append (flatten (car x)) (flatten (cdr x))))
    (t (list x))))

(defun flatten2(l)
  (if l (append (car l) (flatten2 (cdr l))) nil))

(defun flatten3(l)
  (mapcan (lambda(x) (if (listp x) x nil)) l))

(flatten l)
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)

(apply #'append l)
(((1 2) 3) 4 5 6 7)

(flatten2 l)
(((1 2) 3) 4 5 6 7)
```

The further issue is with the usage of `mapcan` in `flatten3`: as `mapcan` hides an `nconc` inside, the user must remember that it **alters its argument**.

```
l
((((1 2) 3) 4) (5 6 7))

(flatten3 l)
(((1 2) 3) 4 5 6 7)

l
((((1 2) 3) 4 5 6 7) (5 6 7))
```

Answer (score 6):

[Dash](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#functions) is a modern list library for Emacs, and has flatten. It's the second most downloaded package on [Melpa](http://melpa.milkbox.net), after magit.  From the [readme](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-flatten-l):

`-flatten (l)`: Takes a nested list `l` and returns its contents as a single, flat list.

```
(-flatten '((1))) ;; => '(1)
(-flatten '((1 (2 3) (((4 (5))))))) ;; => '(1 2 3 4 5)
(-flatten '(1 2 (3 . 4))) ;; => '(1 2 (3 . 4))
```

`-flatten-n (num list)`: Flatten `num` levels of a nested list.

```
(-flatten-n 1 '((1 2) ((3 4) ((5 6))))) ;; => '(1 2 (3 4) ((5 6)))
(-flatten-n 2 '((1 2) ((3 4) ((5 6))))) ;; => '(1 2 3 4 (5 6))
(-flatten-n 3 '((1 2) ((3 4) ((5 6))))) ;; => '(1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

This package was started 2012-09.

Answer (score 3):

I realize that the original question was "what is the built in function".  It appears that there is none.  The other solutions do not actually flatten all lists that I tested.  This function appears to work.  I'm posting it here because this was the first place Google hit when I did my search.

```
(defun flatten (LIST)
  "flattens LIST"
  (cond
   ((atom LIST) (list LIST))
   ((null (cdr LIST)) (flatten (car LIST)))
   (t (append (flatten (car LIST)) (flatten (cdr LIST))))))
```

e.g.

```
(flatten (list "a" (list "b" "c" nil) (list (list "d" "e") "f")))
("a" "b" "c" nil "d" "e" "f")
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `nconc`

Comment: Yeah, that's almost what I was looking for. The only difference is that instead of taking a list of lists as parameter, nconc takes a variable number of lists which it then flattens. But I think that's good enough, although as Gareth pointed out, one has to be aware that nconc is destructive.